# How to avoid saving file to session (Multistep form with CarrierWave file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm implementing a multistep form - as shown in [#217 Multistep Forms - Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) - and came across an error:

```
can't dump File
```

Here are `new` and `create` actions:

```
def new
  session[:batch_params] ||= {}
  @batch = current_user.batches.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @batch }
  end
end

def create
  session[:batch_params].deep_merge!(params[:batch]) if params[:batch]
  @batch = current_user.batches.build(session[:batch_params])

  if @uploaded
    @batch.file = @uploaded
  end

  @batch.current_step = session[:batch_step]

  if params[:back_button]
    @batch.previous_step
  elsif @batch.last_step?
    @batch.file = session[:file]
    @batch.save
  else
    @batch.next_step
  end
  session[:batch_step] = @batch.current_step

  if @batch.new_record?
    render 'new'
  else
    session[:batch_step] = session[:batch_params] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Batch was successfully created"
    redirect_to @batch
  end
end
```

The problem is: the file needs to be updated in the first step, since I need to read it and get the number of rows, to be used on the second step. So I'm trying to store a file in the session, and since it's not possible to serialize it, I'm getting this error.

How can avoid doing this? I believe I should upload the file on the first step, and then just provide it's url to the following steps; is it correct?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create the record on the first form, and use a state machine to track the steps of the object until you fully build it on the last form. Gems like `state_machine` will allow you to do validations per step. The only problem with that is that you might (will) end with submissions that weren't completed. You might clean up this periodically.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of problem I'm trying to avoid. Since `carrierwave` allows me to cache a temporary version of the file, I believe I read the file, and provide the temp path to next steps until the last one, where it would be uploaded. Is it too risky?

Comment: Well, it's temp and I don't think it's survival is guaranteed. All file uploads are stored in a temp file before they are stored in their final locations, do you mind pointing me to the behavior you describe in `carrierwave`

Comment: You're right. Although I don't plan to let the unanswered form persists longer than the session, the file might expire. However, `carrierwave` have a `store` method that allows me to upload the file apart from saving the model; so I believe it's possible to have a persistent file URL before saving the model :) http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/Uploader/Store.html#M000200

Comment: @JoãoDaniel If possible, I suggest you to add how you solved the problem eventually